# Querying a many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a pretty standard many-to-many relationship, similar to the Blog -> Keyword relationship in the ORM tutorial.

I would like to query for a list of Keywords, returning Blog posts where any of them match. However, I can't work out if there is a simple way to do this. If I add multiple filters, repeatedly doing

```
.filter(Blog.keywords.any(Keyword.name == 'keyword'))
```

then I get an 'AND'/'EXISTS' query, such that only posts which have all those keywords would be returned. Is there a simple way to do this as an 'OR' query, or do I need to work using join().

Thanks for any help; I can't work out whether I am missing something.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you just want

```
.filter(Blog.keywords.any(Keyword.name.in_(['keyword1', 'keyword2', ...])))
```

I'm using http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html#common-filter-operators for reference

Comment: Thanks, _in was exactly what I had overlooked.

Comment: If you want this to be fast try: .join(Blog.keywords).filter(Keyword.name.in_(['keyword1', ...])