# SQLAlchemy: Filtering across many-to-many yet returning all results

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Starting from the many-to-many Blog and Tag model and query from [Querying a many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542967/querying-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-sqlalchemy), I know that `session.query(Blog).join(Blog.tags).options(contains_eager(Blog.tags)).filter(Blog.tags.in_(list_of_relevant_tags)).all()` will give me all the blog posts that have at least one of the tags in `list_of_relevant_tags`, and those tags will already have been queried and returned.

The potential problem I see (I'm having trouble testing this) is if I want to get a list of the tags on the returned Blogs. I want to return all the tags, but the generated SQL would suggest that, at best, this would require a second query. At worst, SQLA will only return the tags that matched the list.

Is there a way to submit this query in the ORM to return the matching blog posts along with **all** their tags in one database hit?

Comment: I do not think that you have the problem you fear. The *join* and the *filter* would use completely different objects. If you are not comfortable, just create a test case for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out. It feels like a workaround, though; there's gotta be a more direct way to do this with the ORM.

Basically, you use a subquery of the association table (let's call it `BlogTag` with columns `blog_id` and `tag_id`, that are foreign keys to `blogs.id` and `tags.id`, respectively) to generate a list of `blog_id`s that meet the tag criteria. You then inner join that list of `blog_id`s to an otherwise-unfiltered query of `Blog` joined to `Tag` to return just the relevant `Blog`s.

```
t = session.query(BlogTag.blog_id).filter(BlogTag.tag_id.in_(list_of_relevant_tags)).\
    group_by(BlogTag.blog_id).subquery('t')
blogs = session.query(Blog).join(Blog.tags).join(t, t.c.blog_id == Blog.id).\
    options(contains_eager(Blog.tags)).all()
```