# How to filter InstrumentedList against list of items instead of exactly one object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model that looks like this

```
class Message(db.Model):
    keywords = db.relationship('MessageKeyword', back_populates='message', lazy='subquery')

class Keyword(db.Model):
    messages = db.relationship('MessageKeyword', back_populates='keyword')
```

Now I can filter messages that contain a certain keyword object like this

```
articles = Message.query.filter(Message.keywords.any(keyword=kw))
```

but what if i want to filter messages that contain any a list of keywords `[kw1, kw2, ...]` instead of exactly one kw?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542967/querying-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In other words a definition for MessageKeyword, kw, kw1, and kw2.