# Flask SQLAlchemy query information in many to many relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to query the DB filtered by my order_id and have access to the information for the category_name.

I've tried reading through several answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542967/querying-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-sqlalchemy), but I can't quite get to where I want to be.  I have a models such as:

models.py

```
product_category_table = db.Table('prouct_to_category_association',
db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id')),
db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id')))

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
    risks = db.relationship("Product", 
                        secondary=product_category_table,
                        back_populates="categories")

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Order.id'))
    product_value = db.Column(db.Float(1,2), index=True)
    categories = db.relationship("Category", 
                             secondary=risk_category_table,
                             back_populates="risks")
```

My existing query looks like:

```
products = Product.query.filter_by(order_id = 1).all()
```

and when I want to access the information I am using (in Jinja2 format):

```
{% for product in products %}
cat = {{product.categories}}, val={{product.product_value}}
{% endfor %}
```

This allows me to print:

> `cat = [1], val = 5.99, cat = [2], val = 6.55, and so on...`

However, what I can't figure out is how I can access not just the `category.id`, but the actual `category.name`... I understand why I am getting it `category.id` (from the association table).

**Questions**

1. How do I update my query so the return will have this information?
2. How do I reference it in Jinja?

Comment: It is strange that you receive only `category.id`, because your relationship definitions (`product.category`) should actually return list of `Category` instances.

Comment: @van it could be that I am just screwing up how to reference in Jinja... If I product.categories I get the ID, but if I try product.categories.name I get nothing.  Is that the correct way

Comment: You should be able to loop via `product.categories` via another nested loop such as   `{% for category in product.categories %} cat = {{category.name}} {% endfor %}`

Comment: @van, the nested loop was the answer.  It was delivering the category info as well.  THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

you can make backref in category table

```
risks = db.relationship("Product", 
                    secondary=product_category_table,
                    back_populates="categories",backref=db.backref('cat'))
```

access it using `product.cat.name` or `product.cat.risks` in jinja2
after using backref you can access all the rows of Categories

Comment: SO that throws an error saying that back_populates and backref are mutually exclusive.  If I change to backref it says "relationship 'Product.categories' will copy column product.id to column product_to_category association.product id, which conflicts with relationship Product.category.

Comment: try removing `categories` from `Product`